# Lotus Domino Server Integrated with corporate ldap is fetching garbage values

Tags: active-directory, ibm-domino, ldap

I am using Directory Assistance (da.nsf) to use our corporate ldap for authentication and authorization. Also for sending emails.

While sending emails, i will just give the common name and the server automatically send an email to the user.

But sometimes while sending email, ldap search is giving some garbage values too and hence mailing fails with an error at mail.send(). I have included my DA configuration. I verified corporate ldap and domino directory, both does not have any name like S615. Is there a way to fix that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

S615 is the so called "Soundex" - Value of the name you enter see [this link at IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21084571) to learn more about soundex. Normally Soundex is only checked, if no direct match for a name could be found. I did a short research, but could not find a hint about prohibit Soundex- search.

Regarding [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_RESOLVING_LOCAL_NAMES_STEPS.html&resultof=%22soundex%22%20) it might have something to do with the "Address Lookup" settings in the Configuration Document of the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the research. Hearing about soundex for the first time. I think soundex is coming only because it is searching the domino directory(names.nsf) for names. Is there a way I can specify to search only Active Directory and not names.nsf?

Comment: Yes there is a way to search only Active- Directory. You have to include the ADs' BaseDN in your search to exclude the Entries from Domino- BaseDN (Organisation part defined in your cert.id)